# A third order ordinary differential equation to solve (how to recover this integral solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, mathematical-physics

**Problem statement**: I am trying to derive the integral solution of this third-order ordinary differential equation (ODE) for the function $y(x)$ of the variable $x$

$$y'''(x)=4xy(x), \ \ \ \ \ \ [1] $$

where the primes denote the third derivative with respect to the variable $x$, $y'''\equiv d^3y/dx^3$.

Apparently, one can show that a positive solution of this equation that does not vanish as $x\rightarrow \infty$ can be written as (this condition of non-vanishing solution is a constrain coming from the physics that one imposes here):

$$y= N\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \ \mathrm{exp}(kx)\ \mathrm{exp}(-k^4/16), \ \ \ \ \ \ [2] $$

where $N$ is the normalization constant.

**Question**: I have some difficulties to derive this solution, [2] (even though quickly remplacing [2] into [1] indeed solves the ODE). *Does anyone see how to do it ?*

**My try**: According to the book of Zaitsev and Polyanin on ODE's [L], the general solution for the $n-$th derivative (using their notation):

$$y^{(n)}_x(x) = a x y(x) + b, \ \ \  a > 0$$

reads $$[3] \ \ \ \  y(x) = \sum_{\nu =0}^{n} C_v\epsilon_{v} \int^{\infty}_{0} \mathrm{exp}\left[\epsilon_{v} xt - \frac{t^{n+1}}{a(n+1)}\right]dt, \ \ \epsilon_{v} = \mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{2\pi\nu i}{n+1}\right),$$

where $\sum_{v=0}^{n}C_\nu = \frac{b}{a}$ and $i^2 = -1$. I tried to use [3] with $n = 3$ and $b = 0$ but I could not recover [2].

[L] Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations 2nd Edition
by Valentin F. Zaitsev (Author), Andrei D. Polyanin, 2nd Edition, pp 1052.

Comment: I might think if the conditions in the result in the book you refer to are satisfied before trying to apply that result. Then I would ask if the result you obtain is the same function, just in another expression.

Comment: @NotaChoice thank you for your message. The only condition provided in the book is $a>0$ (in my case $a=4$ which is why I try it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By rescaling $x$ we may eliminate the constant $4$ and study instead the equation

$$
y'''(x)=xy(x)
$$

It is interesting to consider a slight generalization to

$$\tag{1}
y^{(n)}(x)=x^my(x)
$$

By applying WKB methods to (1) we find directly the large $x$ behavior of the $n$ independent solutions is

$$\tag{4}
y(x)\sim N \left(x^{m(1-n)/2n} \right)\exp\left(\omega \int\limits^x dx' {x'}^{m/n}\right)\qquad,\qquad x\to \infty
$$

Where there are $n$ possibilities for $\omega$ such that $\omega^n=1$. For $n=3$ and $m=1$ we have

$$\tag{5}
y(x)\sim N x^{-1/3}\exp\left(3\omega x^{4/3}/4 \right) \qquad,\qquad x\to\infty 
$$

Where $\omega$ has values $1, \ e^{2\pi i/3}, \ e^{4\pi i/3}$. The first corresponds to an exponentially growing function of $x$, the other two are oscillating and exponentially decaying. No linear combination of solutions can go to a nonzero constant for large $x$.

Let us find the solutions to (1) in integral form, which will be possible explicitly if at least one of $m$ or $n$ are equal to $1$.
Taking the Fourier transform (henceforth FT) of (1) we have

$$\tag{6}
(ik)^n\tilde{y}(k)=2\pi (i)^m \int\frac{dk'}{2\pi}\tilde{y}(k') \delta^{(m)}(k-k')
$$

Note that $\delta^{(m)}$ is the mth distributional derivative of Dirac's delta. In obtaining (6), on the LHS we made use of the derivative of FT property. On the RHS we used the 'FT of product of functions equals convolution of their FTs' property. We now have a differential equation for the Fourier coefficients $\tilde{y}$

$$\tag{7}
\tilde{y}^{(m)}=i^{n-m}k^n \tilde{y}
$$

If (7) is easier to solve than (1), we have made progress. It is interesting that when $m=n$, solutions of (1) are equal to their Fourier transform. For $m=1$ (7) is a first order ODE

$$\tag{8}
\tilde{y}'=i^{n-1}k^n\tilde{y}
$$

The solution is

$$\tag{9}
\tilde{y}(k)=N \exp\left(i^{n-1}\frac{k^{n+1}}{n+1} \right)
$$

On taking the inverse FT we have

$$\tag{10}
y(x)=N \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dk}{2\pi} \exp\left(ikx+i^{n-1}\frac{k^{n+1}}{n+1} \right)
$$

Now you need to show (just by substitution) that if

$$\tag{11}
Y_\Gamma(x) =\int\limits_{\Gamma} \frac{dk}{2\pi} \exp\left(ikx+i^{n-1}\frac{k^{n+1}}{n+1} \right)
$$

Then $Y_\Gamma$ satisfies (1) (with $m=1$) *for any curve $\Gamma$ in the complex $k$ plane* so long as the integrand vanishes at the endpoints of $\Gamma$. Linearly independent solutions can be constructed by choosing different endpoints of $\Gamma$. I'll now set $n=3$ for clarity. Then for large $k$ the integrand behaves like $e^{-k^4/4}$. There are four wedges in the complex $k$ plane where the integrand vanishes for large $|k|$. If $k=|k|e^{i\phi}$ then the wedges are in

$$
\phi \in (-\pi/8, \ \pi/8), \quad (3\pi/8, \ 5\pi/8), \quad (7\pi/8, \ 9\pi/8),\quad (11\pi/8, \ 13\pi/8),
$$

Picking $\Gamma$ to begin in the third and end in the first wedge yields the solution

$$\tag{12}
A(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dk}{2\pi}e^{ikx-k^4/4}
$$

Picking $\Gamma$ to begin in the forth and end in the second wedge yields the solution

$$\tag{13}
B(x)=i\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dk}{2\pi}e^{-kx-k^4/4}
$$

Picking $\Gamma$ to begin in the forth and end in the first wedge yields the solution

$$\tag{14}
C(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{dk}{2\pi}(e^{ikx}+ie^{kx})e^{-k^4/4}
$$

Notes:

1. The solution equation [3] in OP appears to be correct. Note that it is *one* particular solution for the inhomogeneous equation, and vanishes when $b=0$, so it's not really helpful for solving the homogeneous problem.
2. This construction is similar to the way integral solutions of the Airy equation; $\operatorname{Ai}$ and $\operatorname{Bi}$ are found.
3. Contrary to my prior assertion, the proposed solution [2] in OP behaves like

$$
y(x)\sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}x^{-1/3}e^{+3x^{4/3}/4}, \qquad, \qquad x\to \infty
$$

Which can be found using Laplace's method. It does not approach a constant, but grows exponentially. It is a linear combination of the $A$, $B$, and $C$ solutions.

4. My FT convention is

$$
f(x)=\int\frac{dk}{2\pi}e^{ikx}\tilde{f}(k) \\
\tilde{f}(k)=\int dx \ e^{-ikx} f(x)
$$

Comment: Thank you for the details ! I have questions first regarding your solution (9): 1) you have an imaginary argument inside the exponential, which is missing in eq (2) of the original post. Is there something I missed ? 2) I know you mentioned that in your post, but why (9) is different from my eq (2) by a factor of 1/4 ? How will the 1/16 appear from your analysis ? 3) Normally, these should be definite integrals (from -$\infty$ to $\infty$), right?

Comment: 1) Yes my $i$ is a result of Fourier analysis, I thought you had one too. 2) my $e^{-k^4/4}$ should be replaced by $e^{-k^4/16}$. 3) All integrals are $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dk$. Note: I will update the answer later tonight

Comment: 1) oh, thank you, that is indeed possible that there is a mistake and a "i" is missing (I only have the final solution on my note). If you confirmed, I will modify my OP 2) Ok but how? Because from (7) putting n = 3, we have a 1/4, no...? 3) perfect !

Comment: Thank you a lot for all the details, @Sal ! Few last questions here: A)  Sorry if trivial, but at the beginning, what do you mean "by rescaling $x$, we may eliminate the 4 ?" In the original equation, we have $d^3 y(x)/dx^3 = 4 x y(x)$, if we do $x^{'} =4 x$,  we have $64 d^3 y(x')/dx'^3 = x' y(x')$, you always have a factor remaining, no ?  B) If we have a factor $C >0$  on the RHS of Eq. (1), then I guess Eq. (9) should be divided by C inside the exponential (to recover the 1/16), right ? C) Based on your post, note 3, does that mean that Eq. (2) of OP diverges as x diverges ?

Comment: let me recast question C) since it is obviously yes, but if we take the more general equation, Eq (10) with the imaginary argument, do you think we also have this divergence as $x$ diverges ?

Comment: Hi, no problem. A) Let $x'=ax$ then substitute into the equation. *Then* choose $a$ to eliminate the constant $4$.  B) This will work for any constant, not just $4$. C) in eq. (5) we have the three possible large $x$ behaviors of the linearly independent solutions. One grows, the other two decay. These are the *only* possible behaviors of solutions. Eq. (10) is not our general solution, it's just a stepping stone to (11) which generates the solutions.

Comment: @math-int did you see my previous comment? I'd appreciate it if you accept an answer if your question has been resolved :)

Comment: Thank you @Sal ! Perfect it should be OK I think I have accepted it now ;)